# Is it 行 or 行く? I am unsure of which one

Tags: grammar, words, syntax, punctuation

I have two sentences:

> 時々、うみえ行くをが好きです。

and

> 母はよく週末に祖父と祖母のいえ行、そこでとまリます。

---

I want to see if both of them are correctly stated, and I believe that the second one might not be. In the first sentence, a く follows from 行, but in the second sentence, it does not. Is there supposed to be a く in the second sentence, or the first sentence, or both?

I am not sure why the く should be in the second sentence, but that makes me unsure if there should be a く in the first sentence. Doesn't 行 mean to go/travel somewhere? What is the dif-ference when we write 行く as opposed to just 行?

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree with @QING. Both examples provided do appear incorrect, which is why it is important to provide a source whenever possible.

Comment: @user27280 my source is schoolwork, but not homework.

Comment: 477343 Not trying to sound flippant, but citing a source as 'schoolwork' is not really sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

These two sentences both are unnatural.

verbs can't come before が　は　を directly. You have to turn them into nouns with の　こと first.

So, you have to speak like this.

> 海へ行く**の**が好きです。
>
> 本を読む**の**が好きです
>
> 先生が話した**こと**を忘れないでください

by the way, if you want speak a man who did two things in **one sentence**, you can use te-from to connect them in japanese.

> 母はよく週末に祖父と祖母の家へ行**って**、そこ**に**とまります。

Also, you should use に in とまります not で。

> あなたのアパート**に**泊まります
>
> 私たちはどこ**に**泊まりますか？

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that te-form. I use it to say my name and my age. Also, I used the word **sokode**, namely, そこで. What does it mean with a に instead of で, i.e. そこに?

Comment: @user477343 maybe, this can help you. my english not so good, I can't speak too much https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9846/に-vs-で-with-state-of-being-but-no-verb

Comment: @user477343 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1290/29959

Comment: @user477343 Yes, you must say *ピアノを弾く**のが**好き*.

Comment: @user477343 を は が must follow の こと, and の こと  must follow the verb.

Comment: I did not mean it like that. I am letting a Japanese decide which is right. When I said it came *before*, I mean from the way I wrote it. I am just confirming if the way I wrote it was correct or not, which I now know it wasn't. I am just having trouble fully understanding. Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

好きなので、時々海へ行きます。

I sometimes go to the beach, because I like it (going to the beach)

海へ行くのが好きです。

I like to go to the beach

母はよく週末に祖父と祖母の家に行って、とまリます。

に is used to indicate the motion of the verbs, and the verb 泊まる can be considered a motion verb. We are actually saying

母はよく週末に祖父と祖母の家に行って、[家に]泊まリます。

But 家に is already mentioned/redundant, so it is omitted.

行く is a verb but 行 is a noun. These sentences are more correct in my opinion.

Comment: I'm saying that your sentences are wrong. "These" refers to the sentence I revised in my answer. Verbs must always end in a kana/letter (called furigana) like 食べる、立つ、学ぶ so that they can conjugated into different forms and tenses. 行くis present tense/future tense (will go), and 行った is the past tense (went). Words like 家、嫌、車 are either nouns/na adjective s/even adverbs when they do not have furigana. Note that not all words containing furigana can be considered a verb. Only specific furigana that represents the conjugations of a verb : 静か is not a verb because there is no か used as conjugations.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. I knew my sentences were wrong; I had a feeling.

Comment: By the way, dekiru, hiragana that change in conjugation are called okurigana, not furigana.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those sentences have some grammatical errors in them. I suspect that, when you say it's "schoolwork" but not homework, these aren't from a specific source, but your own attempt at writing these.

This isn't necessarily bad, but we need to address the parts that are incorrect, why they're incorrect, and some additional information that will aid you in long-term understanding.

Let's start with the first example:

> 時々、うみえ行くをが好きです。

There are a number of items here that are not correct. Please see the correction below:

> 時々、海｛うみ｝**へ**行く**の**が好きです。

I've put in bold the corrections to the issues in the sentence:

1. Even though it is pronounced え, the particle is written with the へ kana.
2. The particle を is used for an action applying onto an object. Liking something is not an object, so its use here is invalid. Here, you require the nominal の particle, to make the action "to go" into a noun-action "going". This, then, is followed by the が particle to express a subject (which is now 海へ行くの = "going to the sea").

As for the second example:

> 母はよく週末に祖父と祖母のいえ行、そこでとまリます。

Let's take the same approach of correcting it first:

> 母はよく週末に祖父と祖母の家{いえ｝**へ**行**って**、そこ**に**とまります。

Here, the things to focus on are these:

1. いえ行 is not a valid construction. Assuming いえ is for house, then you can use the word 家｛いえ｝here just fine. However, because the sentence is talking about "going often to grandfather and grandmother's house", you need to use the direction particle that you needed in the last example, which is へ (which is pronounced え as I mentioned before).
2. 行 is the kanji for the action of going, but it is not in it of itself a complete verb word. The verb that is the actual verb is 行く, and needs to be conjugated based on what you're saying in your sentence. Assuming that the sentence is meant to say "goes often and stays (the night) there", then, you need to use the linking て-form for the verb 行く, which is 行｛い｝って.
3. で is a particle that is used to explain how something happens by means of something else, so it cannot be used here when explaining the location at which something happens. That requires the location particle に instead.

Comment: で can be used to indicate the location where an action takes place and when talking about a specific location you can use で with 泊まる.